# jom with --silent mode

Tags: makefile, silent

I'm using QtCreator (MinGW32 kit) on Windows and trying to make qt project with jom. Project build succeds. **But!** If I use silent mode :

```
CONFIG += silent
```

- build fails. If I look at Compile Output I'll see the error:

```
jom: .....\Makefile  Error
Unexpected appearance: &&.
```

Also what I'll see in Makefile (I'm only displaying blocks where chars "&&" appear):

Compiler, tools and options

```
CC            = @echo compiling $< && gcc
CXX           = @echo compiling $< && g++
LINKER        = @echo linking $@ && g++
```

And then Build rules:

```
@echo moc BooleanSimulationModule.h &&  C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\mingw49_32\bin\moc.exe $(DEFINES) -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/mkspecs/win32-g++ -IE:/qtregistrar/plugins/BooleanSimulationModule -IE:/qtregistrar/tools/widgets/QRWidgets/src -IE:/qtregistrar/tools/widgets/InfPlotWidget -IE:/qtregistrar/reglib -IC:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/include/QtCore BooleanSimulationModule.h -o moc_BooleanSimulationModule.cpp
```

Does anyone have any ideas why jom can't resolve command "&&" and how to fix this?
By the way, mingw32-make can build such Makefile without any probles.

Comment: Because `jom` is "is a clone of nmake" and not GNU (or otherwise) make? And so expects Windows commands and not shell commands?

Comment: Using `@` and then asking us to debug is counter-productive. Take out the `@` in `@echo` and tell us what you get.

Comment: @tripleee Another strange behavior. If I change this line
        `CXX           = @echo compiling $< && g++`
with this 
        `CXX           = g++`
it will work just fine (even thought everything else with `&&` and `@echo` staying the same).